# keep div floating to the left if browser window gets smaller

Tags: html, css-float

I am trying to make some sort of timeline, but I can not **keep the div floating horizontally.**

I have a div container with overflow hidden.
Inside the container I have divs floating to the left.
Inside those div's are ul's with a fixed width.

If I resize the browser, I want the div to be **gracefully cut off from the right side**.

The current situation is that **it floats underneath the previous one** and leaving some **ugly white space**.

How can I maintain everything horizontally?

Any help is appreciated!

thanks in adv, Richard

**EDIT**

```
<STYLE>
    #bericht_container{ border: thin solid #000000; margin-left:20px; overflow:hidden; padding:10px;  width:900px;}
    DIV.bericht_maand{ float:left; margin-left: 20px; border: 2px solid #A0A0A4; }
</STYLE>
```

Comment: Can you provide some example HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap them in a div that is the minimum width you want your page to be.

E.g.

```
#wrapper { width: 900px; }

<div id="wrapper">
    ... Your current HTML ...
</div>
```

You cannot have the div "dissapear" off the edge with CSS, but you could have the page show a horizontal scrollbar when this happens.

Comment: Your width needs to be enough to accomodate both of them side by side.

Comment: Thanks, I have this page where it is done gracefully, but I can't seem to duplicate the same behaviour?http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/advanced-event-timeline-with-php-css-jquery/demo.php

Comment: I think I see it now, It multiply's the divs in the container and sets the width of the container accordingly, I think? But that's jquery stuff. I thought it could be done with pure css.
I will do some more testing to be sure!

Comment: You can use pure CSS - you just need to have your wrapper be at least as wide as the width of the stuff inside of it. It acts as a shield around them so they don't collapse.

Comment: As far as I know though, to get what they have (without a horizontal scrollbar) you have to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I think it should work if you set the div width to 100% and overflow hidden?